# java - slick2d - statebasedgame error - No OpenGL context found in the current thread

Tags: java, opengl, slick2d

I've just started playing with slick2d's state based game structure. I've set up the main class as follows

```
    public static final int newMenu = 0;

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AppGameContainer appgc;
        try {
            appgc = new AppGameContainer(new StateBased("StateBased Test"));
            appgc.setDisplayMode(640, 360, false);
            appgc.start();
        } catch (SlickException e) {
        }
    }

    public StateBased(String name) throws SlickException {
        super(name);
        this.addState(new NewMenu(newMenu));
    }

    @Override
    public void initStatesList(GameContainer gc) throws SlickException {
        this.getState(newMenu).init(gc, this);
    }
```

now the new menu class so far has

```
    private final int state;
    private final Image bg;
    private final static String directory = "Images/StartScreen/";

    public NewMenu(int state) throws SlickException {
        this.state = state;
        bg = new Image(directory + "loadbg.png");
    }
```

but i'm getting at error at the "bg=new image" line. "No OpenGL context found in the current thread." I'm confused since I haven't got this when using basicgame instead of statebasedgame

Can anyone help me solve this

This is the full error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: No OpenGL
>   context found in the current thread.  at
>   org.lwjgl.opengl.GLContext.getCapabilities(GLContext.java:124)    at
>   org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glGetError(GL11.java:1299)  at
>   org.newdawn.slick.opengl.renderer.ImmediateModeOGLRenderer.glGetError(ImmediateModeOGLRenderer.java:384)
>     at
>   org.newdawn.slick.opengl.InternalTextureLoader.getTexture(InternalTextureLoader.java:249)
>     at
>   org.newdawn.slick.opengl.InternalTextureLoader.getTexture(InternalTextureLoader.java:187)
>     at org.newdawn.slick.Image.(Image.java:192)   at
>   org.newdawn.slick.Image.(Image.java:166)    at
>   org.newdawn.slick.Image.(Image.java:154)    at
>   org.newdawn.slick.Image.(Image.java:132)    at
>   statebased.NewMenu.(NewMenu.java:23)    at
>   statebased.StateBased.(StateBased.java:36)
>     at
>   statebased.StateBased.main(StateBased.java:27)

Comment: You're doing too much work in your constructor (`NewMenu`). Add a separate `init (...)` method that you can call ***after*** you have a GL context to load GL resources. As it stands right now, you're doing this before you have a GL context setup.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. Every tutorial I'd seen shows that code in the constructor

Comment: You should write an answer to your question showing what you had to change to fix it. It is perfectly fine to accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by moving the code from the constructor to the init method